Structuring tests in subfolders with Golang
The project I started with go-blueprint has modules like:
./cmd
  ./api
    ./main.go (main)
./internal
  ...
  ./server
    ...
    ./server.go (server -> app/internal/server)
    ...
  ...
./tests
  ./handler_test.go

(Of course, there are a lot more files and folders inside internal.)
Currently, handler_test.go tests ./internal/server/server.go, and doing go test will start that test.
I am used to have tests going in a mirror folder structure, so I would like to have
./internal
  ./server
    ./server.go
./tests
  ./server
    ./server_test.go

Doing that, I can do go test app/tests/server and it does run server_test.go, but no other test.
I tried using t.Run, and I would like to import test functions, however it does not work:
// ./tests/server_test.go
package tests

import (
  testServer "app/tests/server"  // ❌ could not import app/tests/server (no required module provides package "app/tests/server")

  "testing"
)

func TestServer(t *testing.T) {
  t.Run("Testing server routes", testServer.TestBaseRoutes)
}


Maybe I do not understand the paradigm, coming from JUnit, PHPUnit, Jest, etc. but I don't seem to understand how Go structures tests when the app being used is of medium size with, perhaps, dozens of test files.
Is what I'm doing even possible?

Different languages and tools structure tests differently. Go unit tests are compiled and run within a single package only. You put your unit tests in the same package as what they are testing. If you want to execute tests externally from the package you can do so, but you then don't have access to the package internals, and must run those tests separately.

"I am used to have tests going in a mirror folder structure" You have to get use to a different way of placing tests. "I don't seem to understand how Go structures tests" Go is organized in packages. Code and tests of a package live in the same folder. You cannot import "test code". Each package is supposed to be selfcontained, including the tests.

@Volker then why does go-blueprint create an app with a tests folder? Isn't this misleading?

@JimB then why does go-blueprint create an app with a tests folder? Isn't this misleading?

@YanickRochon you'd have to ask them, or consult the docs, it's not a requirement of the language tooling. My best guess is that it's a repository for various integration tests that don't fit in a single package.

@JimB I still do not understand. See, if I have a file in the tests folder, then go test will find it automatically. If I have tests alongside with the files under internal, then Go won't find them unless I do go test ./..., but it will also find other .go files. This is highly inconsistent.

go test on its own doesn't find anything, without a package identifier it assumes the package in the current working directory, and is the same as go test .. The ./... argument is a wildcard which includes packages in the current working directory and all subdirectories.

"if I have a file in the tests folder, then go test will find it automatically" is a factual wrong statement that doesn't match the actual behaviour of go test. "If I have tests alongside with the files under internal, then Go won't find them unless I do go test ./..." again factual wrong. Packages in internal are not different than any other package in regard to testing. You either do go test in the package or go test full/package/import/path. "This is highly inconsistent" only because your assumptions on how go test works do not match the actual behaviour.

Just to mention that you should checkout https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/stretchr/testify/suite package.
Helped me organize tests similar to PHPUnit.

Hello, since we are talking about tests and learning Go, highly recommended: https://quii.gitbook.io/learn-go-with-tests

Go effectively differentiates between white-box testing and black-box testing. With white-box testing, the tests live within the same package as the code you want to test so you have access to the private internals. With black-box testing, a little underappreciated in online articles unfortunately, you place the test code in it's own isolated package so the test code only has access to the public interface of the code you want to test.
The documentation makes specific note of this split.
https://pkg.go.dev/testing
I quote:

The test file can be in the same package as the one being tested, or
in a corresponding package with the suffix "_test".
If the file is in a separate "_test" package, the package being tested
must be imported explicitly and only its exported identifiers may be
used. This is known as "black box" testing.

package abs_test

import (
  "testing"

  "path_to_pkg/abs" 
)

func TestAbs(t *testing.T) {
  // test public abs stuff
}

So that is the convention that Go defines.

White-box test: put tests in a file yourcode_test.go
Black-box test: put test(s) in a subdirectory yourcode_test/yourcode_test.go


Thank you for that explanation, it makes perfect sense!

Your answer is wrong, while black box tests can be declared in a "_test" package, they still should be in the same directory as the source files, not some subdirectory.

@eik Hm, that is painful. I have it setup at home in a different folder based on an existing project I found in git and I quickly googled it and found this article which backed up what I thought was the truth. But I must admit that it's been a while since I touched the setup.

As mentioned in my answer, go test your/package should run all tests for that package, and you want runnable examples in the documentation of the sources. Also, check out the standard library or other popular projects. You can of course have any layout you like, but putting tests in different folders is not “the convention that Go defines.”

Go tests usually live in the same package as the source files. Even go-blueprint recently fixed their templates. If you like a bit more idiomatic project templates, you might want to have a look into gonew.
The point of i.e. Java to separate tests from sources is that testing is not built into the language and you can not deploy a package without including everything in the directory, including eventual tests. So in these languages tests are separate programs in a separate source tree, run by a custom test framework. Also, it's possible to have “split packages” with having sources of a package combined from different directories, which is also not possible in Go.
So, the workaround of keeping tests separated from production code is not needed, and you can keep your tests nicely with your source code.

Note that you should keep all tests with your source code, not in separate folders, even files with a "_test" package for "black box" testing:

Test files that declare a package with the suffix "_test" will be compiled as a
separate package, and then linked and run with the main test binary.

See an example from the standard library.
Why is this important? Firstly, go test <packages> is expected to run all test for the target packages, secondly (as in the example above) testable examples should show up in the documentation of the package.

Thank you for comparing Java and Go in that manner, it makes perfect sense, now!
